# Local continuous martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Hi,

This is a relatively simple [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3VB.png) with a simple proof. However, there are 2 things I don't understand:

1. Why is M a brownian motion?
2. How is I calculated ("Thus, we get...")?

Any insight would be helpful :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

For the first one, this is [Dambis, Dubbins Schwartz Theorem](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/)

For the second one, we need more context but this is (if true) a bit too fast IMO for a proof.

By the way, from where does this come from ?

Regards